# Celery executing parsing file function before the download of the file completes. I am using django +celery

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I have a celery task that requires to download a file from remote server and then parse it. While I tried to it with normal function download() first and then parse(). But celery is executing the parse function even before it downloads which is causing a error is there a way to synchronize these two executions?

```
file.download()   #calling function to download file
file.parse()      #calling function to parse the file
#followed by more code
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a way for chain method.

```
chanin = downdload.s()| parse.s()
chain.apply_async()
```